# How to iterate with condition based on previous rows/columns values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe `df` with datetime index.

```
                    open    high    low     close
DateTime                
2016-02-04 01:00:00 1.10886 1.10887 1.10702 1.10747
2016-02-04 02:00:00 1.10746 1.10893 1.10695 1.10810
2016-02-04 03:00:00 1.10809 1.11403 1.10788 1.11326
2016-02-04 04:00:00 1.11327 1.11673 1.11306 1.11628
2016-02-04 05:00:00 1.11628 1.11835 1.11523 1.11815
2016-02-04 06:00:00 1.11813 1.11848 1.11653 1.11723
2016-02-04 07:00:00 1.11712 1.12020 1.11705 1.11941
```

I need to filter out the indexes where the following condition is met.
It's written in `mql4` code which is where I'm converting this from, so bear with me. Using numbers as indexes so the `bar2Open == 'open'` is the value in the second row prior to the current one and `bar1Low == 'low'` is the value of the previous row:

```
double buffer = 10;
double a = (bar2Open < bar2Close) ? bar1Low : bar1High;
double b = (bar2Open < bar2Close) ? bar3High : bar3Low;
   
if(abs(a-b) >= buffer)
{
  do something;
}
```

I'd like to do this with some form of `itertuples()` but I'm not sure how to access previous rows values in different columns. Output can also be in the form of another column that just gives 1 if the condition is met, 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to iterate over the dataframe rows, that is usually a sign that you are doing something wrong when working with pandas. You can access values from previous rows using [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html). The filtering can be done using something like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

buffer = 10

cond = df['open'].shift(2) < df['close'].shift(2)
a = np.where(cond, df['low'].shift(1), df['high'].shift(1))
b = np.where(cond, df['high'].shift(3), df['low'].shift(3))

idx = np.abs(a - b) > 10
df = df.loc[idx]
```

Using the example dataframe in the question, this will result in an empty dataframe.

---

Assigning an 0 or 1 to a new column can be done using `idx` as follows:

```
df['filter'] = idx.astype(int)
```